# Dispersion of Runge-Kutta methods when applied to systems of ODEs

Tags: numerics, runge-kutta

I am interested in computing the dispersion / phase error(s ?) of an (explicit) Runge-Kutta method when applied to a linear system of ODEs

$$ u'(t) = A u(t). \tag{1} \label{1} $$

To begin, consider the linear test equation
$$u_t = \lambda u = (x + iy) u \tag{2}$$
and a $S$-stage Runge-Kutta method with stability polynomial $G_S = \sum_{i=0}^S \beta_i z^i = \sum_{i=0}^S \beta_i (\Delta t \lambda)^i = \sum_{i=0}^S \beta_i \big(\Delta t (x+iy) \big)^i = (P_S + iF_S)$.
Then, the next state $u_{n+1}$ can be computed as
$$u_{n+1} = G_S u_n = (P_S + iF_S) u_n. \tag{3}$$

[This paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042704002511) recalls a definition first presented in [this publication](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/0724041):

*The Runge-Kutta scheme defined through $G_S$ is dispersive of order $q$ if*

$$ d(\Delta t, y, F_S,P_S) := \Delta t y - \tan^{-1} (F_S/P_S) = \mathcal{O}(\Delta t ^{q+1}) \tag{4} \label{4}.$$

Clearly, I can compute the dispersion $d$ for each eigenvalue $\lambda \in \sigma(A)$ \eqref{4}. Doing so, however, leaves me with a range of different values $d$. I would like to make the connection to an "actual observed dispersion".

For the case that \eqref{1} is the semi-discretization of e.g. the linear advection equation
$$u_t + a u_x = 0 \tag{5}$$
there is a very clear understanding what the dispersion of the Runge-Kutta scheme is:
It is the phase error of the true solution (orange) compared to the numerical one (blue):

[image]

Is there any known relation of the "observed" dispersion and the dispersion(s) computed for the eigenvalues of the system?

Comment: I think to reconcile this you want to remember that (1) you calculate a $d$ value for each eigenvalue precisely *because* numerical dispersion is wavenumber dependent, often more severe for higher-wavenumber modes than lower and (2) your example for the advection equation shows a single Fourier mode rather than a superposition of them.

Comment: Thanks! What exactly do you mean with your second point: Clearly, the displayed $\sin$ wave has exactly one frequency / wave number $k_{\sin}$. Intuitively, I would expect to have higher "observable dispersion" when the dispersions $d$ for the wavenumbers $k_\text{Sys}$ close to the wavenumber $k_{\sin}$ of the $\sin$ are high, and a lower "observable dispersion" when the dispersions $d$ are small for the wavenumbers $k_\text{Sys}$ close to $k_{\sin}$. Is this what you are referring to?

Comment: Yea, what I'm suggesting is that you try the same experiment using another sin wave with double the wavenumber and compare the dispersion.